# Como faço para o próximo laço executar?

Tags: java, loop, while, for

Eu tenho uma lista com duas ou mais Strings:

[Painel, Controle]

Agora vem o problema:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
    String linha = "";
    while ((linha = leitura.readLine()) != null){
        if (linha.contaens(lista.get(i))){
            System.out.println(lista);
```

1 - Executa o for com i igual a 0.

2 - Executa o while e ler linha por linha procurando a primeira string da lista até chegar a `null`.

3 - O for é chamado novamente com i igual a 1.

4 - O while não executa, pois o `leitura.readLine()` vira `null`.

5 - Como faço pro while ser executado até `lista.size()` vezes? Até que a lista a acabe.

No meu código só faz buscar a primeira String da lista, mas a próxima não executa porque a linha virou null na primeira busca.

Comment: não entendi o seu problema. O seu problema é que você tem uma linha como esta? "A B" e você quer pegar primeiro A, depois B?

Comment: Não. Quando o while é executado pela primeira vez, ele é true, agora quando é executado pela segunda vez, ele é false... como deixar ele true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3ll4ry,

gostaria de entender o porque você gostaria de ler a mesma linha 2 vezes para postar uma resposta que melhor se adequa a sua situação.

Mas se você realmente acredita que a melhor maneira seria ler a mesma linha 2 vezes, você tem que fechar o arquivo e abrir ele a cada iteração do for.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
    /* Abre o arquivo, continue utilizando o que você está usando
       para abrir o arquivo, só coloquei o BufferedReader de exemplo */
    BufferedReader leitura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('arquivo.txt');
    String linha = "";
    while ((linha = leitura.readLine()) != null){
        if (linha.contaens(lista.get(i))){
            System.out.println(lista);
        }
    }
    leitura.close(); // Fecha o arquivo
}
```

Isso acontece porque você abre o seu arquivo antes do `for`, lê todas as linhas no seu `while`, mas quando você volta no `for`, o seu arquivo já foi completamente lido.

Comment: É porque cada leitura é uma busca diferente. Resolveu meu problema, obrigado!